# summarise_at dplyr multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply a complex function on multiple columns after applying a group on it.

Code example is:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

add = function(x,y) {
    z = x+y
    return(mean(z))
}

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(.vars=c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width'), 
           .funs =  add('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width' ) )
```

I was expecting that the function would be applied to each group and returned as a new column but I get:

```
Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

How can I get this work?

Note my real problem has a much more complicated function than the simple `add` function I've written here that requires the two columns be fed in as separate entities I can't just sum them first.

Thanks

Comment: `x` and `y` are suppose to be columns of values

Comment: @KillerSnail:You should remove the `' '` from your arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think you need `summarise_at`, since your definition of `add` takes care fo the multiple input arguments. `summarise_at` is useful when you are applying the same change to multiple columns, not for combining them.

If you just want sum of the columns, you can try:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(
    .vars= vars( Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), 
    .funs =  sum)
```

which gives:

```
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
      <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1     setosa          250         171
2 versicolor          297         138
3  virginica          329         149
```

in case you want to add the columns together, you can just do:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise( k = sum(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
```

which gives:

```
     Species     k
      <fctr> <dbl>
1     setosa   422
2 versicolor   435
3  virginica   478
```

using this form with your definition of `add`

```
add = function(x,y) {
  z = x+y
  return(mean(z))
}


iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise( k = add(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
```

returns

```
     Species     k
      <fctr> <dbl>
1     setosa     8
2 versicolor     9
3  virginica    10
```

Answer (score 0):

`summarize()` already allows you to summarize multiple columns.

example:

```
summarize(mean_xvalues = mean(x) , sd_yvalues = sd(y), median_zvalues = median(z))
```

where x,y,z are columns of a dataframe.